# Does a Powershell script using system.managment.automation would still run after its C# host die?

Tags: c#, powershell, runspace

I want to add PowerShell capabilities to a C# program and 
I have embedded the `system.managment.automation.dll` assembly as a reference.
I have found on StackOverflow two ways to call a PowerShell scrit from C# :

- Using runspaces:
- *Not* using runspaces:

  ```
  PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
  powerShell.AddScript("my script");
  powerShell.Invoke();
  ```

According to [this website](https://harrietgl.wordpress.com/2013/09/13/how-to-runspace-part-1/), it seems the Powershell instance is tied to its C# host.

> The Powershell runtime is invoked as a runspace and will, by default, process commands synchronously and deliver the results of processing to the host application so that they can be returned to the user.

Furthermore, the PowerShell script uses the embedded `system.managment.automation.dll` assembly and not the system-wide one, so the script would logically stop with its C# host.

**Does the Powershell script would still run after the user close my program ?** What about the two methods ?

PS: I want to support PowerShell v2.

Comment: When you do `powerShell = PowerShell.Create()` and `powerShell.Invoke()`, a runspace is implicitly created. This runspace will "die" with the host application

Comment: Ok, so the two methods are the same, the first is only a condensed version of the second  ?

Comment: I would argue that the first is less concise (more verbose code), but yes, they are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take this in reverse chronology:

> What about the two methods ?

There's no such thing as running powershell code by "*not* using runspaces".

The simple explanation is that a runspace is a core prerequisite - as the name implies, a runspace is the **space** in which powershell code **run**s.

When you do:

```
PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create()
```

a runspace is implicitly created and attached to the PowerShell instance.

The only difference is that you simply defer control over the Runspace creation to the System.Management.Automation API, rather than instantiating it yourself.

> Does the Powershell script would still run after the user close my program ?

The only circumstance under which the script would continue execution *after* the host application has terminated, would be when you connect to a *remote runspace*, ie. a runspace hosted in another process or on another computer.

Otherwise, the runspace (implicit or not) will be disposed along with the rest of the host application when it exits.

Comment: Is there a way/trick for the PowerShell script to continue after the program die ? (calling PowerShell.exe on the host maybe ?)

Comment: Multiple options. Schedule a task, launch `powershell.exe` etc. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: Alert a user that a file/folder has been created/deleted in a directory specified by the user through a GUI. But this would be just one of the features of the program and I don't want to stop watching this directory because the user closes the program. BTW I have an another idea: creating a new process?

Comment: Schedule a task then (you can use [Register-ScheduledTask](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649811(v=wps.630).aspx))

Comment: But the task would have to be scheduled every 5 seconds in order to be 'live', and I just want it to run for the current session, not after reboot etc...,  an in-memory solution would be better for this no?